# Insert REST / API return in a Component <Text>

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble inserting a request return, each item in its specific location in the application. The value of my response passes as undefined in any situation that I create to insert it in the TEXT component in the body of the application. can you help me please?

my tela.js and my console below:

````
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";
import api from '../services/api';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        nome:"",
    };
  }
  getDateUser(){
    const idcontrato = 8975;
    api.get('http://valoresconsultoria.com/src/post.php?id=' + idcontrato)
    .then(function(response){
    
       this.state.nome = (response.data.nome);
       alert(this.state.nome)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Valor nome:{this.state.nome}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.getDateUser()} title="Clique para somar" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;



[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.nome = response.data.nome')]
* src\pages\profile.js:154:4 in App#getDateUser
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue```
````

Comment: can you put a ```console.log(response)``` inside the api callback to check exactly   what is the response json structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set name to state as follows.

```
  getDateUser = async () => {
    const idcontrato = 8902;
    const response = await api.get('http://valoresconsultoria.com/src/post.php?id=' + idcontrato);

    this.setState({
        name: response.data?.name
    });
  }
```

Comment: Answer accepted because it helped me a lot. But in this case, the return would be for name, cpf, address. 

Example:
{"id_cliente":"8975","nome":"Geraldo da Silva Antunes","cpf":"13069909855"}

so I need to insert each of these data in a separate <TEXT>.

Did you have any suggestions?